# Django forms "pattern" for this situation?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm pretty new to Python so that may be a stupid question but I'll ask it anyway.  Is there a Django forms "design pattern" for this common view situation?  When I run the view, I want it to act on one of two different types of forms depending on the type of user who's filling out the form.  It seems ugly to have two if/then blocks inside the if request.method block to determine which type of form I'm acting on.  What I'd like is to be able to refer to a "CreateProfileForm" that will refer to either a CreateManProfileForm or CreateWomanProfileForm depending on what's in the session variable.

Thanks!

```
def create_profile(request, template):

    if request.session['user_type_cd'] == 'man':
        is_man = True
    else:
        is_man = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        if is_man:
            form = CreateManProfileForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = CreateWomanProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('do-next-thing'))
    else:
        if is_man:
            form = CreateManProfileForm()
        else:
            form = CreateWomanProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Create a dictionary of the forms,

```
FORMS = {
    0: CreateWomanProfileForm,
    1: CreateManProfileForm
}
```

And in the views:

```
def create_profile(request, template):
    is_man = 1 if request.session.get('user_type_cd') == 'man' else 0

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FORMS.get(is_man)(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('do-next-thing'))
    else:
        form = FORMS.get(is_man)()

    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or even this should work

```
def create_profile(request, template):
    is_man = 1 if request.session['user_type_cd'] == 'man' else 0

    form = FORMS.get(is_man)(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('do-next-thing'))

    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```